# MongoDB sorts incorrectly when using an index

Tags: mongodb

Here is the query:

```
db.posts.find({"project.id":5,"project.sections":6,"reading":0,"publicate":1},{"date":1}).sort({"date":-1}).limit(20)
```

And here is the output for it:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("51342351b6f8f38564000001"), "date" : ISODate("2013-03-05T12:38:41.731Z") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("510ff98da80f733357000002"), "date" : ISODate("2013-02-04T19:20:25.618Z") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("50fe4bafb6f8f3a14d000002"), "date" : ISODate("2013-01-22T08:45:16.590Z") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("50fada8ea80f737202000039"), "date" : ISODate("2013-01-19T19:16:23.294Z") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("50e0101fa80f73d664000002"), "date" : ISODate("2012-12-30T09:58:33.881Z") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("50dd54d4b6f8f3923d000014"), "date" : ISODate("2012-12-30T09:52:30.993Z") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("50ccd4a0a80f73b742000008"), "date" : ISODate("2012-12-15T20:58:18.946Z") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("50c0e38eb6f8f32121000018"), "date" : ISODate("2012-12-06T18:35:43.098Z") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("50314562b6f8f3f844000000"), "date" : ISODate("2012-08-22T07:06:54.822Z") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("502012f3b6f8f3df3a000001"), "date" : ISODate("2012-08-06T19:23:10.586Z") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4fe6ea5ab6f8f39f59000000"), "date" : ISODate("2012-06-24T10:25:32.969Z") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("516bbcb2a80f73a55a000000"), "date" : ISODate("2013-04-15T10:36:32.688Z") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("516a5f62a80f733e60000000"), "date" : ISODate("2013-04-14T09:00:19.459Z") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("515e3f2ca80f738536000003"), "date" : ISODate("2013-04-05T03:07:53.960Z") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5155b7c4b6f8f3ad15000001"), "date" : ISODate("2013-03-29T16:18:44.228Z") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("514009e8a80f73f429000001"), "date" : ISODate("2013-03-29T12:31:01.898Z") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("515566d5a80f73437d000005"), "date" : ISODate("2013-03-29T10:10:15.113Z") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("514572cbb6f8f36525000001"), "date" : ISODate("2013-03-17T07:39:33.738Z") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("51432a77b6f8f3024d000000"), "date" : ISODate("2013-03-15T14:07:46.648Z") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("513d4afcb6f8f3727b000000"), "date" : ISODate("2013-03-11T17:46:21.183Z") }
```

As you can see, the order is wrong as if sorting works in some weird way. Here is the output of explain() for that query:

```
"cursor" : "BtreeCursor project.id_1_project.sections_1_reading_1_publicate_1_date_-1",
"nscanned" : 929,
"nscannedObjects" : 915,
"n" : 8,
"millis" : 23,
"nYields" : 0,
"nChunkSkips" : 0,
"isMultiKey" : true,
"indexOnly" : false,
"indexBounds" : {
...}
```

But if I disable the index it sorts fine:

```
db.posts.find({"project.id":5,"project.sections":3,"reading":0,"publicate":1},{"date":1}).hint({$natural:1}).sort({"date":-1}).limit(20)

{ "_id" : ObjectId("51475ee4b6f8f3526f000004"), "date" : ISODate("2013-04-16T10:51:04.962Z") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5166e61fa80f73b658000001"), "date" : ISODate("2013-04-11T16:58:11.848Z") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("514afc12a80f735162000000"), "date" : ISODate("2013-03-25T02:51:18.309Z") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("513db351b6f8f3d601000006"), "date" : ISODate("2013-03-11T10:49:27.585Z") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5105ff74a80f739704000006"), "date" : ISODate("2013-02-19T11:19:57.448Z") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5121de84b6f8f3b20c000009"), "date" : ISODate("2013-02-18T07:58:40.779Z") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("511dbc4ab6f8f3a550000006"), "date" : ISODate("2013-02-15T04:51:39.767Z") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("51053aafa80f73ae74000002"), "date" : ISODate("2013-01-27T14:44:48.931Z") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("50f1c7c4b6f8f3ed2e000003"), "date" : ISODate("2013-01-12T20:48:04.451Z") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("50ec5111b6f8f3180e000034"), "date" : ISODate("2013-01-09T10:25:50.736Z") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("50d36076b6f8f3707400000f"), "date" : ISODate("2012-12-20T19:14:40.412Z") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("50b4f7b6b6f8f3d261000003"), "date" : ISODate("2012-11-27T17:52:24.675Z") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("50a0b83eb6f8f30a74000001"), "date" : ISODate("2012-11-12T09:14:04.652Z") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5092746eb6f8f3c92d000000"), "date" : ISODate("2012-11-06T12:02:21.634Z") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("50926d48b6f8f31d15000000"), "date" : ISODate("2012-11-01T13:11:40.107Z") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("508a471cb6f8f33568000000"), "date" : ISODate("2012-10-26T19:41:50.516Z") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("508998c5b6f8f3b977000000"), "date" : ISODate("2012-10-26T07:59:18.278Z") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5088c043b6f8f3442b000003"), "date" : ISODate("2012-10-25T05:08:12.372Z") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("50857833b6f8f37770000001"), "date" : ISODate("2012-10-22T17:06:37.667Z") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("507e2f0ab6f8f34c2d000000"), "date" : ISODate("2012-10-17T04:32:10.337Z") }
```

I have tried rebuilding the index for the whole collection using db.bla.reIndex(), it didn't help. All other queries on the same collection that use the same index work just fine.

MongoDB 2.0.9

What could be the reason behind this behaviour?

Comment: Your query has a limit of 10 documents, but your result you're showing contains more than 10 documents. Is the output really the content of your query?

Comment: Sorry, my bad, just changed the limit and mixed up the lines. It is the correct output though, double checked.

Comment: Out of interest, what is the index you made? What fields was it on?

Comment: It is an index for this kind of queries exactly: project.id_1_project.sections_1_reading_1_publicate_1_date_-1

Comment: Hmm out of interest again, if you took out the multikey fields `project.id` and `project.sections` does it work?

Comment: Tried that, doesn't seem to be any problems. As I said, other values works fine too, for example, `project.id:2`.

Comment: Hmm I must admit, that is...really confusing, I'll keep thinking.

Comment: It really is.. Thank you, I'll try the mailing list as well.

Comment: What version of MongoDB are you using?

Comment: 2.0.9 (added to the post)

Comment: what does .explain() tells you for these queries?

Comment: philnate, added the output of explain() to the post.

Answer (score 1):

You are sorting by dates. Then limiting output.
MongoDB is fetching documents according to query with dates ordered. Then cutting first 20 records. Now MongoDb has 20 records of previously ordered set of ObjectIDs. MongoDB is showing these 20 set without the order. Because last "limit" line creates a set of documents and find command gets whatever in the set without ordering. You have to chain another sort command like this:

```
db.posts.find({"project.id":5,"project.sections":6,"reading":0,"publicate":1},{"date":1}).sort({"date":-1}).limit(20).sort({"date":-1}))
```

It may seem awkward but it is actually naturally ordered. Suppose that you want to get the list of documents in the natural order but you want just first 20 ones with recent dates. Your query is just doing it. But if you want a list of documents ordered by date, you should use one more sort command at the end of query to do it.

Comment: Chaining this sort command will not work since you have no actually queried the server yet as such no command has been sent to the server